# Outlook disconnected from Exchange server every time I switch networks

Tags: networking, microsoft-outlook, exchange

For the last month or so, my Outlook application lose the connection with the Exchange server every time I switch networks on my laptop. The only thing that resolves the problem is to restart Outlook. All other applications work fine, including Teams.

Things I have tried:

- Clicking "Send / Receive -> Work Offline", waiting until the status bar shows "Working Offline" and then clicking "Work Offline" again. Status bar changes back to "Disconnected".
- Repairing the Outlook installation (online repair)
- Running "ipconfig /flushdns"
- Clicking "Send / Receive -> Download Headers". Error message: Task [e-mail address] reported error (0x80040115) : 'We can't complete this because we can't contact the server right now. Please try again later.'
- Ctrl-clicking the Outlook icon in the systray, selecting "Connection status..." and then clicking "Reconnect".

I'm connected to two different Exchange 365 accounts, my employer's and my client's. Both gets disconnected when I switch networks. At work I'm connected over Ethernet and use a Zscaler proxy to access internet (but I think Exchange traffic is allowed through the firewall without having to enable the proxy). At home I'm connected over Wifi, no proxy.

Installed versions:

- Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2310 Build 16.0.16924.20054) 64-bit
- Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, version 10.0.19045 Build 19045

Comment: In order to further confirm the issue, you can try add you accounts in other computers to check if the issue persists.